# What's the default font that Eclipse uses on Mac OS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos, fonts, default

What is the default font used by Eclipse on OS X systems?

I often watch Java videos and I'm in love with that font.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an Apple-provided font called Monaco. However, in newer versions of OS X often other, similar fonts e.g. Menlo are used (e.g. in Apple's dev environment, XCode).